# In iOS different location detected even when device is in one position

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using the [following code](https://github.com/voyage11/Location) to detect location changes for a particular user. However, even if I keep the iPhone in the same location for a few minutes, the iPhone detects changes in the location. Following are the different latitude longitudes it detected when the iPhone was in the same location. Here is some outputs:
    {latitude = "22.46812";
    longitude = "88.39014";} 
    {latitude = "22.46814";
    longitude = "88.39017";}
    {latitude = "22.46813";
    longitude = "88.39016";} and so on...

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: This is due to GPS precision. The location is never really very accurate, and it can have minor changes.
Here, it change of about `0.00001°`, this is a very small change (about 5 feet or 1.5m)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get accurate data?

Comment: See "moving average", here for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Answer (score 1):

This has alot to do with GPS precision. For example the satellites in space are moving and the earth is moving. GPS is never "exact" for long periods of time, it may have your exact coordination for x amount of time. As the Earth continue to move just like the sats in the sky trying to triangulate your location.

Long story short your GPS location is never static just approximate. :D Your code is fine, your app is fine.